# Creating VCS specific synonyms of version-control tags

Tags: discussion

There's been a request here [Automatically backing up uploaded files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48868/automatically-backing-up-uploaded-files) as a comment to create [svn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svn), [subversion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subversion) and [git](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) tags as synonyms of [version-control](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control).

I'm personally not sure this is a great idea - but perhaps it should be up for discussion as I'm guessing that a fair few version control questions might be better suited on Stack Overflow?

On the other hand, the proposed synonyms don't actually exists as current tags, so they may not be missed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag synonyms are created when there are users who keep using two different tags for the same purpose. If users keep using [d7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d7), and [dr7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr7) to mean the question is about Drupal 7, then those tags would be made synonym of [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7).
In the specific case, [git](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) is not a synonym of [version-control](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control), as the tags have different meanings.

Tags are not created before they are used; there must be a question using them. Users with [a reputation of at least 300](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) can add new tags to their own questions, while users with [a reputation of at least 500](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) can retag questions.

Keep in mind that tags used from only a question are automatically removed after a month.

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea.  Take the question [When is using --package-handler=git_drupalorg appropriate with drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46362/when-is-using-package-handler-git-drupalorg-appropriate-with-drush)  This is specifically about drush and some of it's built in git features, not about drush and general version control.

Answer (score 2):

As the person asking the linked question this meta question stems from, I think I'm agreeing with Chapabu and MPD that it's a bad idea to make [git](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) and [subversion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subversion) synonymous with [version-control](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control).

That said, I think there is a need for VCS-related tags (Instead of just pushing those questions to SO) given Drupal-specific uses of them -- for instance, my question ultimately is asking for a way to hook up an Image field to some sort of VCS. The point MPD is making about drush's use of VCS is another -- I confused myself hardcore just the other day when trying to update a site using Drush because Drush didn't like my working copy.

So, in short:

1. The synonyms idea was a bad one -- please disregard.
2. But that said, having a tag for Subversion might be helpful (with tag synonym "svn"). While git is clearly the technology of choice for the Drupal-sphere (For good reason too, I might add), forcing SVN users into using the general "version-control" tag isn't smart for the same reason not to force git users into it -- it requires a specific specialized knowledge.

(That said, I think it's safe to not add tags for any VCS that isn't supported by Drush.)

Comment: The reason that there is no SVN tag is that there haven't been any questions that have explicitly needed it.  If a question gets asked, then the tag will be created.

Comment: @MPD -- /me points at my question about SVN. "Hi! :)"

Comment: I read that question as asking about versioning the files directory and not about using SVN to version to files directory, hence me not adding that tag.